# chrome doesnt support date format using spring mvc

Tags: java, google-chrome, date, spring-mvc

I am trying to submit a form in chrome browser that containing a date field but it doesn't work.
here my entity.java :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = " dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date lieferdatum;
```

my page.jsp :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label><fmt:message code="common.lieferdatum" /></label>
  <f:input  id="lieferdatum" path="lieferdatum" class="form-control" placeholder="lierferdatum" type ="date" />
</div>
                                `
```

when i use it with chrome i got this error :

> org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'user' on field 'lieferdatum': rejected value
>   [2017-12-13]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.user.lieferdatum,typeMismatch.lieferdatum,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch];
>   arguments

any help?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN web docs `<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the actual value — the displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's browser, whereas the date value is always formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`.

So the date value sent to server side is in format `yyyy-MM-dd`. However, your Spring date pattern is set to `dd/MM/yyyy`, thus it causes a type mismatch. Changing the date-format to [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format should work:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date lieferdatum;
```